# Modify the "arrow" with of a split button in TActionToolBar

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a toolbar using TActionToolBar and TActionManager. A button has sub-buttons that are available clicking the small down arrow placed in the right of the button.

The width of the "arrow down" button is very thin and requires precise mouse control. How can I customize it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A solution is using the OnGetControlClass event of TActionToolBar.

Before, it is necessary to derive a class from TThemedDropDownButton and override the GetDropDownButtonWidth function:

```
function TThemedDropDownButtonEx.GetDropDownButtonWidth: Integer;
begin
      Result := 14; // default drop down button width
end;
```

Then, in OnGetControlClass function:

```
void __fastcall TWorkAreaToolBarFrame::ActionToolBarLeftGetControlClass(TCustomActionBar *Sender,
 TActionClient *AnItem, TCustomActionControlClass &ControlClass)
{
    if(ControlClass == __classid(TThemedDropDownButton))
        ControlClass = __classid(TThemedDropDownButtonEx);
}
```

In few words, in GetControlClass event, the toolbar allows you to define which button class you want to use. We use a custom class with the default width changed.